# Embed multiple excel files in a word document, displayed as icons

Tags: vb.net, excel, ms-word

I am able to copy a single excel file into a word document, displayed as an icon. But when i select multiple files from a folder, what happens is each of the files get copied into a new word document. In other words, I am unable to embed multiple files at a time into a single word document.

Also here in my code i have to create a bookmark from begining into the word document. I want to create the bookmark in the word document dynamically through code.

Could anyone please guide me how i can create bookmarks dynamically through code and also how can i embed many files at a time into a single word document.

Here is my working code that embeds only one file at a time.

```
 Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim ofd As New OpenFileDialog
    ofd.InitialDirectory = My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.MyDocuments
    ofd.Filter = "Excel Files (*.xls;xlsx)|*.xls;xlsx"
    ofd.FilterIndex = 2
    ofd.RestoreDirectory = True
    ofd.Multiselect = True

    Dim Files As String = ofd.InitialDirectory
    If ofd.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then

        For Each Files In ofd.FileNames

            Dim filename As String = ofd.FileName

            Dim oWord As Word.Application = New Word.Application()
            Dim oWordDoc As Word.Document = oWord.Documents.Open("C:\testing.doc", False)
            Dim oMissing As Object = System.Reflection.Missing.Value
            oWord.Visible = True


            'ICON LABEL CAN BE THE NAME OF THE FILE, 
            'ITS THE NAME DISPLAYED BESIDES THE EMBEDDED DOCUMENT

            Dim oIconLabel As Object = filename                


            'THE BOOKMARK WHERE THE FILE NEEDS TO BE EMBEDDED
            Dim oBookMark As Object = "ssss"
            '//THE LOCATION OF THE FILE
            Dim oFileDesignInfo As Object = filename


            '//OTHER VARIABLES
            Dim oClassType As Object = "Word.Document.8"
            Dim oTrue As Object = True
            Dim oFalse As Object = False
            'Dim oMissing As Object = System.Reflection.Missing.Value
            Dim oIconFileName As Object = oMissing

            'METHOD TO EMBED THE DOCUMENT

            oWordDoc.Bookmarks.Item(oBookMark).Range.InlineShapes.AddOLEObject(oClassType, oFileDesignInfo, _
            oFalse, oTrue, oIconFileName, oMissing, oIconLabel, oMissing)

            Next
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code to open a new word instance and load the document is within the loop - move it out of the loop so you only run it once.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
                 ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim ofd As New OpenFileDialog
    ofd.InitialDirectory = My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.MyDocuments
    ofd.Filter = "Excel Files (*.xls;xlsx)|*.xls;xlsx"
    ofd.FilterIndex = 2
    ofd.RestoreDirectory = True
    ofd.Multiselect = True

    Dim Files As String = ofd.InitialDirectory
    If ofd.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then

        Dim oWord As Word.Application = New Word.Application()
        Dim oWordDoc As Word.Document = oWord.Documents.Open("C:\testing.doc", False)
        Dim oMissing As Object = System.Reflection.Missing.Value
        oWord.Visible = True

        For Each Files In ofd.FileNames
            '*************
            'rest of code....
            '*************
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Tim...thanks for the help. There is one more problem in my code...Though i select multiple files, only the last file gets copied that too as many times as many files i have selected. In other words, if i select 5 files, only the last file i select gets copied 5 times and its named as the whole folder path where its located. Could you help me out with this. Also i still am not able to create a bookmark dynamically in the word document.

Comment: When you have `For Each file In ofd.FileNames` then within the loop `file` has the full path to the file.  You can use `Path.GetFileName(file)` to extract the name of the file from the path. You're also using `"Word.Document.8"` as the classname for your embedded files, but the files you're adding are Excel...   Sorry - don't have VB.NET on my machine so can't provide a full set of code.

Comment: Tim...I am able to copy all the multiple files properly.. Had to just change the word filename with Files and its working perfectly...
Only that i couldn't get how to create a bookmark in the word doc dynamically through code....Thanks anyways

Answer (score 0):

Finally have done it successfully...Here is the working code:

```
    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim ofd As New OpenFileDialog
    ofd.InitialDirectory = My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.MyDocuments
    ofd.Filter = "Excel Files (*.xls;xlsx)|*.xls;xlsx"
    ofd.FilterIndex = 2
    ofd.RestoreDirectory = True
    ofd.Multiselect = True

    Dim Files As String

    If ofd.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then

        Dim oWord As Word.Application = New Word.Application()
        Dim oWordDoc As Word.Document = oWord.Documents.Open("C:\testing.doc", True)
        Dim oBookmark As Object = oWordDoc.Bookmarks.Add("Bookmark")
        Dim oMissing As Object = System.Reflection.Missing.Value
        oWord.Visible = True

        For Each Files In ofd.FileNames

            'ICON LABEL CAN BE THE NAME OF THE FILE, 
            'ITS THE NAME DISPLAYED BESIDES THE EMBEDDED DOCUMENT
            Dim oIconLabel As Object = Path.GetFileName(Files)

            '//INCASE WE NEED THE EMBEDDED DOCUMENT TO BE DISPLAYED AS A SPECIFIC ICON,
            '//WE NEED TO SPECIFY THE LOCATION OF THE ICON FILE
            '//ELSE SET IT TO oMissing VALUE
            'Dim oIconFileName As Object = "C:\\Document and Settings\\IconFile.ico"

            '//THE LOCATION OF THE FILE
            Dim oFileDesignInfo As Object = Files

            '//OTHER VARIABLES
            Dim oClassType As Object = "Word.Document.8"
            Dim oTrue As Object = True
            Dim oFalse As Object = False
            'Dim oMissing As Object = System.Reflection.Missing.Value
            Dim oIconFileName As Object = oMissing

            '//METHOD TO EMBED THE DOCUMENT

            oWordDoc.Bookmarks.Item(oBookMark).Range.InlineShapes.AddOLEObject(oClassType, oFileDesignInfo, _
            oFalse, oTrue, oIconFileName, oMissing, oIconLabel, oMissing)

        Next
    End If

    Me.Close()
End Sub
```